# XPM in Embedded Schema Fields its not able to update except index value in Razor Template?

Tags: web8, experience-manager, razormediator, embedded-items

[image]Razor Code

```
@FieldStartMarker("Component.Fields.footerquicklinks")
  @FieldValueStartMarker() 
   <span class="links">@Component.Fields.footerquicklinks.quicklinktitle</span>
  @FieldValueEndMarker()
@FieldEndMarker()
```